# How can I group by distinct value in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table I have the following columns:

- account_id (int)
- customer_type (text)
- advice_started_at (timestamp)

I am looking to extract the hour in advice started_at from each account, grouping them together to show the percentage of entries that take place at each hour of the day.

So far, I have:

```
SELECT
    account_id,
    customer_type,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(advice_started_at :: TIMESTAMP)) AS time_hour
FROM
    customer_advice
ORDER BY
    time_hour
```

This gives a table of the following format:

| account_id | customer_type | time_hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bb318ee8-598e-4bde-908e-be630076830f | First time Buyer | 0 |
| bfb8920b-7bd1-4e64-a2a5-1ff5d754a475 | FirstTimeBuyer | 1 |
| 66dbbaf2-9b0f-4424-8131-a416b46bd0eb | Remortgage | 7 |

All account ids have an associated time_hour. I'd like to group these time_hours together to understand what percentage of account_ids are represented by each hour from 0-24.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but: `(HOUR FROM(advice_started_at :: TIMESTAMP))` can be simplified to `(HOUR FROM advice_started_at)` there is no need to cast a `timestamp` column to a `timestamp` value

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you wanna do:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(advice_started_at)) AS time_hour
    , count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()* 100 as percentage
FROM
    customer_advice
group BY
    time_hour
```

this is only by hour overall your data , if you want the percentage per hour per day , you need to group by day/hour as well:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('hour' ,advice_started_at) time_hour
    , count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()* 100 as percentage
FROM
    customer_advice
group BY
    time_hour
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM advice_started_at::TIMESTAMP) AS time_hour,
       COUNT(*) as cnt,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
FROM customer_advice
GROUP BY time_hour
ORDER BY time_hour;
```

If you want all hours even if some have missing data, you need a `LEFT JOIN`.  I might suggest:

```
SELECT time_hour,
       COALESCE(cnt, 0) as cnt,
       COALESCE(ratio, 0) as ratio
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 23) gs(time_hour) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM advice_started_at::TIMESTAMP) AS time_hour,
             COUNT(*) as cnt,
             COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
      FROM customer_advice
      GROUP BY time_hour
     ) hh
     USING (time_hour)
ORDER BY time_hour;
```